# How can I load a Dockerfile into K8s (AKS) with a .properties file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following project:
https://github.com/ably/kafka-connect-ably

Running the dockerfile locally works perfectly well.
I have tried a few methods to get it working in k8s...

I have tried Kompose. This created the correct .yaml files, as well as a persistent volume properly linked with the mountpath "config", but when run I get the error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /config/docker-compose-worker-distributed.properties
```

Is there a way I can add the properties file to the persistent volume?
I have tried

```
kubectl cp config/docker-compose-worker-distributed.properties connector:/
```

but I get:

```
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("connector")
```

I have also tried tagging the image with docker tag mycontainerreg.azure.io/name and then docker pushing, but that also fails, perhaps because not enough resources are allocated to it?

Mainly I just need the connector to port from Kafka (Apache) running in AKS to Ably, I understand I can add the connector to Confluent cloud if I purchase Enterprise but thats expensive!

Comment: You probably need to put the properties file into a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).  Have you looked into that approach at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone finds this. I ended up using Confluent and hosting it in AWS, which meant I could use the bring your own connector / custom connector feature.
Very nice feature allows you just to upload a zip of your connector and they host it for you.

Not technically an answer to the question but it means I dont need to find a solution any more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a configMap file that will contains the properties and specify it in your deployment.yml

This is an exemple of a configMap named **properties.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kafka-properties
binaryData:
  propertieA: >- valueA
```

In your deployment yaml file you need to add the reference to the configMap created

```
 volumes:
       - name: kafka-properties-volume
         configMap:
           name: kafka-properties
```

check the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) about configMaps

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't supply a file. The container already has it, and mounting one may get overridden by the container entrypoint script, as that's what the Confluent images do

[Install the linked plugin into a container such as Confluent connect image](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/extending.html) (that's what their Dockerfile already does, but uses Maven rather than Confluent Hub client, which also works with Apache Kafka), or use Strimzi (rather than Kompose) and you can either configure the worker property file with environment variables like `CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`, or with Kafka Connect Strimzi resource spec natively with k8s resource files. This will template the distributed worker properties file as part of the container startup process

Connectors themselves would be configured with JSON payload to the REST API, not files